# He reached the summit in an hour

Tags: prepositions, time-words

> Peter started climbing the mountain. He reached the summit **in** an hour.

What does "in" mean in this sentence?

I've consulted some dictionaries, but haven't found the correct explanation. I think "in an hour" means an hour after he began to climb, but can't find this meaning in Random House Learner's Dictionary of American English or Collins Concise English Dictionary or https://www.thefreedictionary.com/in.

Comment: Please include what you think it means, what dictionaries or other online resources have told you, and why you're still unsure. The purpose of this is so people answering don't tell you things you already know.

Comment: Yes, it means that it took him (about) an hour to climb to the summit.

Comment: It's [1a](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/in) "within the limits..of"

Comment: If it means within the limit of, does my sentence mean he could've reached the summit 56, 57, or 59 minutes after he began?